# How do I filter token accounts by amount of tokens?

Tags: anchor, web3.js

I understand how to use memcmp to get accounts for a particular token using `getParsedProgramAccounts`, however since memcmp is an equality, I can't really query for "greater than" a certain amount. What is the idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: the `memcmp` filters don't have a mechanism for non-equative comparisons. if you're querying for a specific owner, it would be best to use `memcmp` to get all of the token accounts owned by a specific owner, deserialize the data and filter from there

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that you can. I followed the typescript definitions and looks like you need add exact amount. this is the typescript definition for `getParsedProgramAccounts`

```
Connection.getParsedProgramAccounts(programId: PublicKey, configOrCommitment?: GetParsedProgramAccountsConfig | Commitment | undefined): Promise<{
    pubkey: PublicKey;
    account: AccountInfo<...>;
}[]>
```

this is `GetParsedProgramAccountsConfig` of `configOrCommitment`

```
 type GetParsedProgramAccountsConfig = {
    /** Optional commitment level */
    commitment?: Commitment;
    /** Optional array of filters to apply to accounts */
    filters?: GetProgramAccountsFilter[];
    /** The minimum slot that the request can be evaluated at */
    minContextSlot?: number;
  };
```

this is the `GetProgramAccountsFilter`:

```
 type GetProgramAccountsFilter = MemcmpFilter | DataSizeFilter;
```

this is `MemcmpFilter`

```
type MemcmpFilter = {
    memcmp: {
      /** offset into program account data to start comparison */
      offset: number;
      /** data to match, as base-58 encoded string and limited to less than 129 bytes */
      bytes: string;
    };
  };
```

and this is `DataSizeFilter`

```
type DataSizeFilter = {
    /** Size of data for program account data length comparison */
    dataSize: number;
  };
  /**
```